# MYSQL Populate date field under specific rules

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if i could get some help with a query in mysql. The following is what i have come up with so far:

```
CASE
WHEN Field1 = ''
     OR Field1 IS NULL
     AND Field2 <> ''
     OR Field2 IS NOT NULL
     AND Field3 = 'Monthly'
     AND Field4 >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
     OR Field3 = 'quarterly'
     AND Field4 >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH)
     OR Field3 = 'semi'
     AND Field4 >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH)
     OR Field3 = 'yearly'
     AND Field4 >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH) THEN Field4
ELSE ''
END AS Field4,
```

Basically what i'm trying to do is when field1 is blank but field2 is not blank commence with the next step which is:

when field3 is Monthly and field4 is the same or greater than the current date but not less than 1 month ago
or when field3 is quarterly and field4 is the same or greater than the current date but not less than 3 months ago
or when field3 is semi and field4 is the same or greater than the current date but not less than 6 months ago
or when field3 is Annually and field4 is the same or greater than the current date but not less than 12 months ago

Then populate field4 otherwise make it blank

Would greatly appreciate any help, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some parentheses might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgot parenthesis.

`AND` have precedence over `OR` in SQL, so if you write your condition like `WHERE a OR b AND c`, that means `WHERE a OR (b AND c)` not `WHERE (a OR b) AND c`.

Also there shouldn't be `OR` between Field2 conditions, but `AND`.

Your query should look something like this:

```
CASE
WHEN (Field1 = '' OR Field1 IS NULL)
    AND Field2 <> ''
    AND Field2 IS NOT NULL
    AND (
         (Field3 = 'Monthly'
             AND Field4 >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
         OR (Field3 = 'quarterly'
             AND Field4 >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
         OR (Field3 = 'semi'
             AND Field4 >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
         OR (Field3 = 'yearly'
             AND Field4 >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH))
    )
THEN Field4
ELSE ''
END AS Field4,
```

You can also try this shorter syntax, but I'm not sure this will work. I have no MySQL available at the moment to test it.

```
CASE
WHEN (Field1 = '' OR Field1 IS NULL)
    AND Field2 <> ''
    AND Field2 IS NOT NULL
    AND Field4 >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),
        INTERVAL
            (CASE Field3
                WHEN 'Monthly'   THEN 1
                WHEN 'quarterly' THEN 3
                WHEN 'semi'      THEN 6
                WHEN 'yearly'    THEN 12
            END)
        MONTH)
THEN Field4
ELSE ''
END AS Field4,
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, i knew i needed parentheses but was not sure how to implement it in this case statement. The first answer worked but had to make 1 change which was AND Field4 >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)) i believe should be AND Field4 >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)) i only noticed when evaluating the output on my end. Thanks once again!

Comment: BTW, have you tested my second answer? Do it work too?